# Suggestions on Feature selection techniques?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-analysis, feature-selection, data-science

> Blockquote

I am a student and  beginner in Machine Learning. I want to do feature
selection  of columns.  My dataset is 50000 X 370 and it is a  binary 
classification problem.
First i removed the columns with std.deviation = 0, then i removed duplicate columns, After that i checked out top 20 features with highest ROC curve area. What should be the next step apart doing PCA? Can anybody give a sequence of steps to be followed for feature selection?

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing a lot of preprocessing. The only additional step I recommend is to normalize the values after PCA. Then your data should be ready to be fed into your learning algorithm.

Or do you want to avoid PCA? If the correlation between your features is not too strong, this might be ok. Then skip PCA and just normalize the values.

Comment: Okay, i got it for first part. Can you comment on second part of problem.

Comment: There is no fixed sequence of steps. All the preprocessing steps you metioned make sense in most cases. Others have mentioned additional steps like L1 regularization or Random Forest which also have certain advantages. But my main advice is: Don't overdo it. Leave some work to be done for your learning algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try L1 regularization. It's the standard way of removing less relevant features.

http://www.andrewng.org/portfolio/feature-selection-l1-vs-l2-regularization-and-rotational-invariance/

Answer (score 0):

You may try following techniques/algorithms:

1. **L1 regularization:** This will generate sparse feature matrix; most feature weights will be zero. But this technique is useful if you have high-dimensional dataset, which seems true in your case. There are algorithms which does not support regularization.
2. **Sequential feature selection:** Can be useful for algorithms those don't support regularization. Such algorithms automatically select a subset of features which are more relevant to the problem. You can find more about this here: (1) [Comparative Study of Techniques for Large Scale Feature Selection](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.24.4369), F. Ferri, P. Pudil, M. Hatef, and J. Kittler. Comparative study of techniques for large-scale feature selection. Pattern Recognition in Practice IV, pages 403– 413, 1994. (2) [Feature selection in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html).
3. **Dimentionality Reduction:** PCA(Principal component analysis) and LDA(Linear Discriminant Analysis) will work well if your problem is linear i.e. your data is linearly separable. If data is not linearly separable, then you can try kernel principle component analysis.
4. **Feature importance with Random Forest:** This is an ensemble technique which will give you feature importances(numerical values). You may discard features with low importances.

Comment: I know that Random forest works on information gain. So if i choose only first 20 variables whose information gain is max. Then can i say that i don't need to do pca, regularization and other methods as i have top 20 performing features? Am i right in saying that?

Comment: If you are very specific about selecting best 20 features, then the answer is yes.